# Angular ui-router $state.go is not redirecting inside resolve

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

In my angularjs app, I am checking if user lands on landing page and is already authenticated, then redirect him to home page.

```
.state('landingpage', {
            abstract: "true",
            url: "/landingpage",
            templateUrl: "app/landingpage/landingpage.html",
            resolve: {
                AutoLoginCheck: ['$state', '$window', function ($state, $window) {

                    if($window.localStorage.access_token != null)
                    {
                        if($window.sessionStorage.access_token == null) {
                            $window.sessionStorage.access_token = $window.localStorage.access_token;
                        }
                        UserInfoService.SetUserAuthenticated(true);

                        // it is not redirecting
                        return $state.go('app.home');

                    }
                }]
            }
        })
```

The problem is that though all the resolve code is successfully run, user is not getting redirected to app.home. Can someone tell why this happens?

**Note**: The state 'app' also has a resolve in which it fetches the data to be displayed in 'app.home' state.

Comment: $state doesnot work with resolve.

Comment: Why and can you explain what does?

Comment: I believe this can be solved the same way as answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36728528/846727)

Comment: `event.preventDefault()`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There can be two solutions to your problem

- Firstly you can emit an event and the listener will  handle your state transition. You can implement the listener in anywhere in a parent controller
- Secondly you can implement the $stateChangeStart hook and check your redirection condition there

  ```
  $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, toState) {      
       if (toState.name === 'landingpage') {              
         if (!isAuthenticated()) { // Check if user allowed to transition                  
              event.preventDefault();   // Prevent migration to default state                  
              $state.go('home.dashboard');           
          }
        }
  });
  ```

Comment: Where should this condition be put?

Comment: Also, you have not injected $state too. Am not sure if this works.

Comment: this is placed inside the run block and $rootScope and $state are injected there `run(function ($rootScope, $state){
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, toState) {
      if (toState.name === 'landingpage') {
        if (!isAuthenticated())
           event.preventDefault();  $state.go('home.dashboard');
        }
      }     
    });`

Answer (score 29):

```
.state('landingpage', {
            abstract: "true",
            url: "/landingpage",
            templateUrl: "app/landingpage/landingpage.html",
            resolve: {
                AutoLoginCheck: ['$state','$window', '$q','$timeout', function ($state, $window,$q,$timeout) {

                    if($window.localStorage.access_token != null)
                    {
                        if($window.sessionStorage.access_token == null) {
                            $window.sessionStorage.access_token = $window.localStorage.access_token;
                        }
                        UserInfoService.SetUserAuthenticated(true);


                        $timeout(function() {
                           $state.go('app.home')
                        },0);
                        return $q.reject()

                    }
                }]
            }
        })
```

This would work for you.

Comment: Could you also add an explanation?

Comment: @Robert: Inside resolve the only thing possible is reject or resolve the promise. I think state.go() is not possible unless we add it up in callstack using timeout.

Comment: I did similar to this but whithout $timeout, like this: `return $q.reject().catch(function(){$state.go('app.home'); return $q.reject();})` then you lower the number of injects

Comment: @Gustav: yours doesn't work for me, while Shyjal's does.

Comment: Let the record show that @Gustav 's answer is the absolute best. It may also be appropriate to send some sort of error object with the `reject` and let `$stateChangeError` do the rerouting in my case I actually wanted to use the `$state.go` promise to run some logic after the redirect. And this was perfect.

Answer (score 13):

You can use `$location.url('/')` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can use resolve to provide your controller with content or data that is custom to the state. resolve is an optional map of dependencies which should be injected into the controller.

You could have a controller that checks for the AuthState and have the redirection accordingly.

```
     .state('landingpage', {
        abstract: "true",
        url: "/landingpage",
        templateUrl: "app/landingpage/landingpage.html",
        resolve: {
            AutoLoginCheck: ['$window', function ($window) {

                if($window.localStorage.access_token != null)
                {
                    if($window.sessionStorage.access_token == null) {
                        $window.sessionStorage.access_token = $window.localStorage.access_token;
                    }

                   //assuming userInfoService does the authentication
                    var isAuthenticated = userInfoService.SetUserAuthenticated(true);
                    return isAuthenticated;

                }
            }]
        },
        controller: ['$state','AutoLoginCheck', function($state, AutoLoginCheck){
          if(AutoLoginCheck){
            //authenticated
            $state.go('app.home');
          } else {
            //redirect to unauthenticated page
            $state.go('....');
          }
        }]
    })
```

Comment: I like this approach, but suppose I need to secure my routes and need to check user authorization at every route he accesses. I would need to duplicate this everywhere right? I have lots of routes in my app.

Comment: Also, I tried this, and the page redirected correctly, but not before displaying the current page for a split second. Is there a way to stop directing to current state while the controller redirects?

Comment: I would suggest to have the auth/redirect logic at a root level abstract state and so all the the states that are protected will go as nested. But this would need all your states updated though. And for adding delays, you could consider using $timeout before hitting the auth state.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old thread, but I use $location.path() to accomplish redirection inside of a state.resolve() block

Answer (score 0):

Anyway resolve waiting for promise state . Best thing what you can do is return promise and add timeout for your state:

```js
resolve: {
    AutoLoginCheck: ['$state', '$window', '$timeout', '$q', function ($state, $window, $timeout, $q) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        if(user.isLogin()){
             deferred.resolve();
        }else{
          $timeout(function(){
            $state.go('app.home');
          }
          deferred.reject();
        }
        return deferred.promise;
    }]
```