# How to redirect in a ui-router resolver?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am trying to redirect inside a ui-router resolve and wanted to know if there is a way to reroute in a router resolver. Currently this does not work as one would think.

```
resolver(auth, $state){
   if(!auth.isLoggedIn()){
       $state.go('noLoggedInPath');
   }
}
```

**How does one redirect in a resolver correctly ?**

My temp hack is this but I am not comfortable with it.

```
resolver(auth, $state, $timeout){
   if(!auth.isLoggedIn()){
        $timeout(function () {

             $state.go('noLoggedInPath');
        }, 0);
   }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure about redirecting inside a resolver, but if what you want is to check whether the user is logged in or not, perhaps you can use the `$stateChangeStart` event instead.

Comment: @FranDios The reason to use log in check in resolver is so that we don't have to specify in statechange which url not to check.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You can return a promise from your `resolver` function that will indicate whether to continue navigating to the state or not. If you decide to navigate somewhere else - reject the promise and specify the proper state:

```
resolver($q, $state, $timeout, auth) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();

    // $timeout is an example; it also can be an xhr request or any other async function
    $timeout(function() {
      if (!auth.isLoggedIn()) {
        // user is not logged, do not proceed
        // instead, go to a different page
        $state.go('noLoggedInPath');
        deferred.reject();
      } else {
        // everything is fine, proceed
        deferred.resolve();
      }
    });

    return deferred.promise;
}
```

Plunkr [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/4aW48y4ZgGI67drGASpP?p=preview).

UPD: updated code and added plunkr. Looks like it only works if you put it inside a timeout function.

Comment: That approach doesn't seem to redirect

Comment: @EdgarMartinez Ok, I played a bit with plunkr and realized that redirect only works if it's placed inside of some async function (timeout is the simplest option). Please check if it works for you.

Comment: OK I think my solution so far as noted above is just the way it is going to be for the time being

Comment: Did you found out why you had to do this? I don't understand why we have to use the timeout in order to make this work. I have the same problem and in order to fix it i have to use the timeout.

Comment: I think you'd better leave only the redirection in `$timeout`
`var deferred = $q.defer();
        if (true) {
          $timeout(function() {
            $state.go('error');
            deferred.reject();
          });
        } else {
          deferred.resolve();
        }
        return deferred.promise;`

Comment: @Marcio the reason you need the $timeout in this case is because you need to first return the Promise for Angular to hook onto it, then reject it (remember, a promise is something that allows to hook onto while waiting for an async action to complete). In this case, the async action is $timeout (instead of the usual $http call).

Answer (score 48):

Yauheni's answer does work, but to get around the weird timeout thing, you can reject the promise, and catch that in the $stateChangeError event, and do your redirect there. Like so...

```
state('admin', {
  resolve: {
    auth: function(UserService, $q, permissionService) {
      var deferred = $q.defer();
      return UserService.load().then(function(user){
        if (permissionService.can(user, {goTo: state})) {
          return deferred.resolve({});
        } else {
          return deferred.reject({redirectTo: 'some_other_state'});
        }
      });
    }
  }
});
```

And then ui-router always broadcasts "stateChangeError", so you can do something like this..

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeError', function(evt, to, toParams, from, fromParams, error) {
  if (error.redirectTo) {
    $state.go(error.redirectTo);
  } else {
    $state.go('error', {status: error.status})
  }
})
```

Comment: This should be the correct answer. The `resolver` should only be used to resolve/reject dependencies.

Comment: nah @Kunal. While this may be more "idiomatic", it has a problem of splitting the routing logic all over the place. That's worse from a practical point of view. Think maintainability.

Comment: @UAvalos The routing logic lives in exactly the same places it does as in the accepted answer (which is exactly 2). You have a states file and an error catcher for redirects. This answer just says, "hey, you're already redirecting 404's and such in the error handler, so let's also redirect auth errors in that same spot." In both cases, the "if cantAuth --> go "somewhere" *intention* is in the same place (the resolver). This answer just cleans it up a bit by removing an unneeded timeout.

Comment: @bwest87 what if the error handler depends on the page that you're trying to visit? That's the use case that I'm talking about. In the app that I'm working on that results in distributed logic. Which is bad because it's a very large app

Comment: @UAvalos This answer allows you to pass in arbitrary options to your error handler. In my example code, I pass in a `{redirectTo: state}` object that tells the error handler exactly which state to go to. Thus it has error handler logic that depends on the page you're trying to visit, exactly as you describe. If you need even more, like say... you want to pass a custom message, then I would suggest just passing that in too, like `{redirectTo: state, message: customMessage}`, and your error handler can deal with that. The infrastructure is flexible. Or am I not understanding your problem?

Comment: Ah you're right! Just tell the error handler where to go. Yes, that handles my use case. And if you need an arbitrary action, pass a callback

Comment: How do you do this using the new API? $state.go seems to not work inside the $transitions.onError handler

Comment: @UAvalos I'm not totally sure about new API's. But the example above works on $stateChangeError, not $transitions.onError. According to these docs (updated 23 days ago: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki), $stateChangeError still looks like the place to catch errors. But perhaps that changed in some new version I'm unaware of.

Answer (score 10):

I use this

```
   function Check($state, $q) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        if (condition) {
            deferred.resolve();
        }
        else {
            deferred.reject();
        }
        return deferred.promise.catch(function () { $state.go('path'); });
    }
```

Comment: It does work! And it's very clean and simple! Why did someone mark a minus score on it?

Comment: I love this solution! very clear and easy to understand! @Benson, you rock! I would mark this answer as accepted

Comment: I get a "ransition Rejection($id: 0 type: 2, message: The transition has been superseded by a different transition, detail:...." error in my console when doing this. It does what I want, but error message.

Answer (score 2):

This is what I actually do, and I can't find a better solution

```
resolver($q, $timeout, myService) {
    if(!areParameterValuesValid() || !isEverythingLogicallyOk()){
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        $timeout(function() {
            $state.go('somewhere');
            deferred.reject();
        });
        return deferred.promise;
    } else {
        return myService.loadSomething(passingSomeParams);
    }        
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think a much cleaner answer is to return an already rejected promise like so:

```js
resolver(auth, $state, $q){
   if(!auth.isLoggedIn()){
       $state.go('noLoggedInPath');
       
       // Return rejected promise
       return $q.reject();
   }
   return true;
}
```

Comment: Strange, it works for me. Maybe it changed in a different AngularJS/UI-Router version?

Comment: I haven't tried this yet, but according to this it should be the accepted answer: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/3331#issuecomment-279081347

Comment: @DanKing this is exactly what my answer is doing. Does a `$state.go` then return a rejected promise `$q.reject()`. Thanks for the extra info!

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant - sorry @Tibo. I was trying to say that yours should be the accepted answer, because it's the same as the link that I provided.

Answer (score 0):

You can use resolver promises from with the redirectTo configuration

```
   redirectTo: function($transition$) {
      return $transition$.injector().getAsync('isNew').then(function(isNew) {
        return isNew ? 'estate.edit' : 'estate.view';
      });
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

Using resolves for this didn't quite work out for me. I adapted the logic from [this post](http://www.summa.com/blog/angular-ui-router-an-elegant-maintainable-way-to-prevent-state-change) to execute a redirect function on the [data](https://ui-router.github.io/ng1/docs/latest/interfaces/state.statedeclaration.html#data) property of the state object. You can then tap into the $stateChangeStart event on $rootScope from the run block of the module and use the injector service's invoke method to the change the state based on the conditions you specify. Works nicely across modules as well.