# How to properly redirect in angular UI-Router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am trying to use resolve and conditional routing in angular ui-router but it doesnt seem to work

App.js:

```
app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $stateProvider

    .state('app', {
    url: '/app',
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: 'templates/home.html'
  })


  .state('app.login', {
    url: '/login',
    views: {
      'menuContent': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/login.html'
      }
    }
  })

  .state('app.therapist', {
    url: '/therapist',
    views: {
      'menuContent': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/therapist.html'
      }
    }


  }).state('app.trial', {
    url: '/trial',
    views: {
      'menuContent': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/trial.html'
      }
    },
    resolve:{
      check:function($state){
        if(1==1){
           e.preventDefault();
          $state.go('app.login',{}) ;  /**/Here trying**
        }else{
          return true;
        }
      }
    }
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/app/therapist');

  });
```

So in app.trail route I was testing and trying to redirect to app.login but it doesnt work it only opens the trial page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `e.preventDefault();` you appear to be missing anything defined as `e`.

You can use `preventDefault()` when handling an event such as `$stateChangeStart`, but I don't think that is available within `resolve`.

See [Angular ui-router $state.go is not redirecting inside resolve](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29080128/angular-ui-router-state-go-is-not-redirecting-inside-resolve) for some suggestions on how to handle this (do the check inside a handler for `$stateChangeStart`, or send an event to trigger the transition, or use a timeout to delay your state change until after the first one has completed).

Comment: I read in another question to include this but anyways how would I make this work ?I am relatively a beginner.Thanks